# I am trying to create a c program that will continuously take inputs from stdin till exit is entered

Tags: c, cycle

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char str[SIZE];
  char str2[] = "exit";
  //fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
  while (strcmp(str, str2) != 0)
  {
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    printf("%s", str);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to exit and is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: The string returned by `fgets` will include the newline (`\n`) character. Try using `strncmp(str, str2, 4) != 0`.

Comment: `str` is uninitialised the first time through; maybe use a different looping mechanism?

Comment: @AdrianMole that would match, eg, `exiting`.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/10871073).

Comment: @Neil - well spotted!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to use:

```
char str2[]="exit\n";
```

But a `do - while` cycle would be best:

```
int main () {    
    char str[SIZE];
    char str2[]="exit\n";
    do {
        fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
        printf("%s",str);
    } while(strcmp(str,str2));
    return 0; 
}
```

Since in the first iteration of you cycle `str` is empty.

Comment: This is probably the most lazy ways imaginable, (and one of the fastest.) I approve.

Comment: @rohithp, glad to help, extended credits to [Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871073/adrian-mole) and [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2472827/neil)